# Regex to match line containing Two words

Tags: regex, expression

Below is my Content:

```
Subject:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-21-3368353891-1012177287-890106238-22451
    Account Name:       ChamaraKer
    Account Domain:     JIC
    Logon ID:       0x1fffb

Object:
    Object Server:  Security
    Object Type:    File
    Object Name:    D:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\logs\localhost.2013-07-01.log
    Handle ID:  0x11dc
```

I need to match the line containing `Object Name` using a Regular expression.

Following is what i have tried:

```
^.*\b(Object|Name)\b.*$
```

The above regex matches `Account Name:       ChamaraKer`, But my requirement is to match the line containing the word `Object Name`. How can i do this? It would be great if any one could help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is actually trying to match lines that contains Object **OR** Name..

Change it it

```
^.*\bObject Name\b.*$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question if you could help me with. I need to capture the words after the `Object Name:` in that line. How do i do that? Pls help me

Answer (score 1):

Response to comment:

```
^.*\bObject Name:(.*)$
```

Group 1 will have everything match inside of (.*).

Depending on regex engine, for example it'll be `\1` (for Notepad++) or `match.Groups[1].Value` (C#)